# How to edit each variable inside object in arraylist

Tags: arraylist, netbeans-7

please help me. i'm new in programming. i have some assignment to submit.
i use Netbeans. i want to edit a specific data about a student whose matric number is given. First, the system will prompt for the matric number of the student. If found, the system will ask the user on the data to be edited (either name or matric or age or mark). The user will specify which data and then the system will ask the user to enter the new value for the data. After setting the data with the new value, the system will display all data about the student.
Here is my codes :

Class :

public class Student {

```
int matric;
String name;
int age;
double mark;
String grade;

Student(int m, String n, int a, double mk) {
    matric = m;
    name = n;
    age = a;
    mark = mk;
}


public String computeGrade() {

    return "";
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(int name) {
    this.matric = name;
}

public int getMatric() {
    return matric;
}

public void setMatric(int matric) {
    this.matric = matric;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public double getMark() {
    return mark;
}

public void setMark(double mark) {
    this.mark = mark;
}








else if (choice == 4) {
            System.out.println ("Edit Student Data");
            System.out.print("Enter the matric number>");
            int matric = read.nextInt();
            boolean found=false;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                if (myStud[i].getMatric() == matric) {
                    System.out.println("======================================");
                    System.out.println("Student Name = " + myStud[i].getName());
                    System.out.println("Student Matric = " + myStud[i].getMatric());
                    System.out.println("Student Age = " + myStud[i].getAge());
                    System.out.println("Student Mark = " + myStud[i].getMark());
                    System.out.println("Student Grade = " + myStud[i].computeGrade());
                    System.out.println("======================================");

                    found=true;



                        System.out.println("1. Edit Name");
                        System.out.println("2. Edit Matric");
                        System.out.println("3. Edit Age");
                        System.out.println("4. Edit Mark");
                        System.out.print ("Please choose data to edit > ");                        
                        int edit = read.nextInt();


                        if(edit == 1){
                        System.out.println("Enter Your Name ");                            
                        String name = read.next ();

                        }
                        else if(edit == 2){
                        System.out.println("Enter Your Matric ");
                        matric = read.nextInt ();

                        }
                        else if(edit == 3){
                        System.out.println("Enter Your Age ");
                        int age = read.nextInt ();
                        // **how to save and replace the oldest?**
                        }
                        else if(edit == 4){
                        System.out.println("Enter Your Mark ");
                        int mark = read.nextInt ();

                        }

                System.out.println("Student Data has been updated!");
                break;
                } 
            }
            if (found==false)
            System.out.println("Student Data not Found!");
        }
```

Comment: This code will not compile - you introduce an `else` term without an `if` or even a method!

Comment: that is just part of if statement..

Comment: There's lots of other code missing, I don't know what `**how to save and replace the oldest?**` means, and why wouldn't `myStud[i].setAge(age)` work?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have an array, NOT ArrayList. You can do like:

```
myStud[i].setAge(readValue);
```

for editing age attribute of i-th object in array.

Is that the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Your welcome. Please select my answer as accepted :)